# Calculations on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project and I can't wrap my head around on a calculation that needs to be done on a multidimensional array. Quick background, it's a hotel benchmarking tool and I need to calculate the market penetration index (MPI). I have an array with 3 main arrays. First 2 are the hotels which are being compared and the last one is the MPI array.

Each array contains an array  for every month the user selects. Inside THAT array is data that needs to be used for calculations.
Here is an example:

```
Array
(
 [Competitive set] => Array
    (
        [Sep 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-09-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-09-01
                        [nrcheck] => 13
                        [data] => 67.6
                    )

            )

        [Oct 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-10-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-10-01
                        [nrcheck] => 13
                        [data] => 63.6
                    )

            )

        [Nov 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-11-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-11-01
                        [nrcheck] => 13
                        [data] => 59.2
                    )

            )

        [Dec 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-12-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-12-01
                        [nrcheck] => 13
                        [data] => 54.6
                    )

            )

    )

[Test] => Array
    (
        [Sep 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-09-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-09-01
                        [nrcheck] => 89
                        [data] => 71.5
                    )

            )

        [Oct 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-10-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-10-01
                        [nrcheck] => 89
                        [data] => 67.0
                    )

            )

        [Nov 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-11-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-11-01
                        [nrcheck] => 91
                        [data] => 63.1
                    )

            )

        [Dec 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-12-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-12-01
                        [nrcheck] => 89
                        [data] => 57.5
                    )

            )

    )

[MPI] => Array
    (
        [Sep 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-09-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-09-01
                        [nrcheck] => 89
                        [data] => 71.5
                    )

            )

        [Oct 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-10-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-10-01
                        [nrcheck] => 89
                        [data] => 67.0
                    )

            )

        [Nov 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-11-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-11-01
                        [nrcheck] => 91
                        [data] => 63.1
                    )

            )

        [Dec 11] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minmonth] => 2011-12-01
                        [maxmonth] => 2011-12-01
                        [nrcheck] => 89
                        [data] => 57.5
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

here is a pastebin with var_export as suggested (can't seem to format it propperly here)
http://pastebin.com/b8hYM7TW
Sorry for the huge code block but it had to be this big =(
Either way currently the  'data' for MPI is wrong. That needs to become the data of the first array divided by the data of the second array and multiplied by 100 (percentage).

The keys "Competitive Set" and "Test" are variable and not available in the scope i'm working in so those static names can't be used.

I read about recursive functions but I'm still not getting it...

Comment: if you want code handouts, at least make it easy for someone to help. use var_export()

Comment: Added as a pastebin until I can get the formatting right. What is the difference between var_export and print_r in terms of making it easier to help?

Comment: From the PHP.Manual:
'var_export() gets structured information about the given variable. It is similar to var_dump() with one exception: the returned representation is valid PHP code.'

Comment: Yes I realized that a couple of minutes ago! I didn't know that was possible. Very nice!

Comment: From what I see in the data you pasted, Dit Hotel has '-' as its data item so you can't really do any calculations with that. Are you doing MPI = (Dit Hotel['month']/Test['month'])*100 ? Also, could each month have more than one data value? If not, there are a bunch of assumptions you could make so that you dont really need a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well the pastebin array you provided doesn't have any data in the "Dit hotel" array, so I can't really confirm this works, but here you go

```
foreach ($array['Dit hotel'] as $key => $value) {

    $array['MPI'][$key][0]['data'] = $value[0]['data'] / $array['Test'][$key][0]['data'] * 100;
}
```

http://codepad.org/m884GMpJ